# Big table size in PostgreSQL while number of rows is small

Tags: postgresql-9.1

Tables' size in the PostgreSQL DB are big while the number of rows is relatively small (less then 500K rows).
Vacuum of the specific table did not solve the problem.
Only by deleting and importing the table from a previous dump file did solve the problem: the tables' size are back to normal. Consequently, all the queries on these tables became very fast while they were lasting for long before the import operation.
Note: auto vacuum is on by default

Answer (score 1):

Autovacuum doesn't try to release space back to the OS. That's often counterproductive to do, since PostgreSQL would just have to allocate it again later, and allocating new storage is slower than re-using already allocated storage.

If you want to release space back to the operating system you can use `VACUUM FULL` on the table(s) in question, or the whole database. This will actually make tables with lots of inserts/updates *slower* unless you also set a `FILLFACTOR` of less than 100 first so there's space reserved.

Answer (score 1):

try this out from your shell

```
$ vacuumdb -f -v -e -d your_database_name;
```

It will physically delete the blocks or pages from the data base thatis still not freed up after your deletion.
or you can run something for a specific table

```
postgres=# VACUUM (VERBOSE, FULL) v4report.tbl_gps_final;
```